# How to update iOS app with exception of a file

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, settings, sandbox

I'm making my first iOS app. And I have a question.In my app I want to save the current state of the app: levels completed, score reached, money, in-App purchases, etc. in a Settings.plist. The problem is, how can I place this plist so that if the user updates the app, he/she not to lose these settings. I read about The app sandbox, but I don't understand
how it works, and how can I manage that from Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

You should store these settings in the **NSUserDefaults**. They are kept when new app versions are installed, so you won't have any problems.

Comment: Why di you want to do it otherwise

Comment: That's the easiest way - why do you have a problem doing it like that?

Comment: Because I have written a complete singleton class that saves the current game state and looks like this : [[GameState sharedGameState] saveCurrentState]; And I want not to change my whole code.

Comment: Then just save the stats in that singleton class' function using NSUserDefaults - no problem there ...

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

a) When you update your app after its in the app store by submitting a new version *of the same app* the files created by the old version will not be lost. So you can store whatever you like in the app's Document or Library directories and expect it to still be there after an update. The Library/Caches directory will not be backed up or restored by iTunes so don't put anything there that you can't re-create. If you submit a different version of the app (not an update but a new app, so you have two separate apps in the app store, perhaps free and paid) there is no way that I know of for the new version to get to the files that the first version created.

b) It's easy for the user to read, delete, or change whatever files you create in Documents/ or Library/. It can be done with an app on his/her Mac such as iExplorer (downloadable from macroplant.com). So be aware that if the file is human-readable, which a .plist file is, the user can change it to improve his/her score, get more consumables, or whatever. You can prevent that by encrypting the data, or somehow obscuring the meaning, or by some kind of checksum scheme so you can at least detect that it was changed. Any of those measures involve complications of course and may not be worth the trouble.

BTW... if you're developing an app that uses data files iExplorer is a great debugging tool. I have no vested interest in it except that I've learned how to use it and want it to continue to be supported. There are probably other apps that do the same thing but this one works great and is fast and easy to use.